# Wireless Network Storage

Tags: nas

I am wondering if there is any sort of adapter that I could plug in a IDE HDD into and it would offer something similar to a NAS-server on a Ethernet or Wireless (WiFi) network, anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Devices like [this](http://www.tweaktown.com/news/21167/sharkoon_adds_gigabit_ethernet_to_quickport_pro_hdd_dock/index.html) or [this](http://www.inxtron.com/network-attached-storage/clouddock) would do the trick, or anything else you could find with "hard drive dock +ethernet" parameters on a search-engine.
If you have an old throw-away computer with a SATA-interface, the FreeNAS distros may do the job as well.